# How to compare a string in a C program

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a question about how to compare strings in an `if` statement. I am moving from Python to C and the comparing strings is easy in Python, but in C how do I do it?

My program is:

```
printf("Enter your choice 1.add\n 2.sub\n 3.mul\n 4.div\n");
string choice = get_string();

if (choice == "add")
{
    int c = calculate_add(a, b);
    printf("sum of %i and %i is %i\n", a, b, c);
}
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
calculate.c:19:16: error: result of comparison against a string literal is
  unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Werror,-Wstring-compare]
if (choice == "add")
           ^  ~~~~~
```

It says use `strncmp` to compare the string, but how do I do it?

Comment: Is this line correct string choice = get_string();?

Comment: "_but i don't know how to do it_" - Google, research and learn. There are a lot of examples in the web. Did you check them out?

Comment: @lazy_coder ya that's correct because i included cs50 header file :)

Comment: @CoolGuy that's good advice but stack is way more better than google :)

Comment: @pkarthicbz Yes, but for these kind of beginner questions, use google. There are a lot of examples you can get from there. If you read the tooltip of  the downvote button, you'll see something like 'Post has shown no research effort'. People will downvote. That's to keep up the good quality of questions. You could've found out how to use `strcmp` much faster if you had googled it. Consult Stack Overflow only _after_ your research fails you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `strcmp` from `<string.h>`

```
#include <string.h> // It might compile without it, but always add it for portability and so that your code compiles in all compilers that follow the C standard.

int main() {
   int equals = strcmp("add", "add") == 0; // equals = true

   int greaterThan = strcmp("bad", "add") > 0; // greaterThan = 1

   int lessThan =  strcmp("123", "add) < 0; // lessThan < 0

}
```

**So in your case:**

```
if (strcmp(choice, "add") == 0) { // This means choice = "add"
    int c = calculate_add(a, b);
    printf("sum of %i and %i is %i\n", a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: No prob! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply instead of

```
if(choice == "add")
```

use the following syntax:

```
if(!strcmp(choice, "add"))
```

Don't forget to `include <string.h>`.